# How to check to see if a string has three words in row?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I am a beginner programer and I am working on a programming problem. My program is supposed to split a string into the separate words/numbers and then check to see if there are three words in a row within the string. Some of the inputs are yielding a False return when it should return true.

```
def words(words):
    count = 0
    for phrase in words.split():
        if phrase.isalpha():
            count +=1
        else:
            count = 0
    while (count <3):
        return False
    return True

words("Hello World hello")#True
words("He is 123 man")#False
words("1 2 3 4")#False
words("bla bla bla bla")#True
words("Hi") #False
words("one two 3 four five six 7 eight 9 ten eleven 12") #True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking *after* the `for` loop completes, you should return in the middle of the `for` loop as soon as `count` reaches `3`, otherwise it could get reset to 0 after a 3-count has already been found.

```
def words(words):
    count = 0
    for phrase in words.split():
        if phrase.isalpha():
            count +=1
        else:
            count = 0
        if count == 3:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to check the count within the iteration, otherwise you're only checking if the LAST 3 phrases are words.

```
def words(words):
    count = 0
    for phrase in words.split():
        if phrase.isalpha():
            count +=1
            if count == 3:
                return True
        else:
            count = 0
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your problem correctly, you wanna get True for last input `"one two 3 four five six 7 eight 9 ten eleven 12"` because there is `four five six` in a row.

the problem in your code is because it will continue the for loop until end of words. For input above, count end up as 0 because the words endswith `12`.

code below will return True whenever it hit 3 words in a row. Otherwise, continue the for loop.

```
def words(words):
    count = 0
    for phrase in words.split():
        if phrase.isalpha():
            count +=1
        else:
            count = 0
        if count >= 3:
            return True
    return False
```